# HtmlElement not showing child nodes but HtmlElement.asXml() method does

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have a web page from which I have saved in an HtmlPage object. I applied an XPath and its result is being stored in a list.

```
List<?> items = null;
items = page.getByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'search-result-cards')]/div[contains(@class,'listContainer')]");
```

Now what I observed, is that when I iterate through these items, using HtmlElement, I get just the first line of the div tag which contains the class listContainer but not its child nodes. However, on using he.asXml() method, I get the complete information about the subnodes as well.

```
for(HtmlElement he : (List<HtmlElement>) items)
{
    br.write("Printing just the element ::: "+he);
    br.write(he.asXml());
}
```

Here, `br` is a BufferedWriter object which is being used to write the output to the file.
The issue is that I want all this information which is coming after I'm calling `he.asXml()` method in the HtmlElement object only. Is it possible? I tried typecasting directly a string to HtmlElement Object which didn't work. Can anyone please help?

```
Output
Printing just the element ::: HtmlDivision[<div class="listContainer" data-ptitle="3139847000" data-reactid="402">]

he.asXml() Output
<div class="listContainer" data-ptitle="3139847000" data-reactid="402">
<div class="imageContainer" data-reactid="403">
<div class="prodInfoContainer" data-reactid="406">
.
.
.
```

The dots represents these nodes keep on going, as the output is very large.
Let me know if any other information is needed that I may have not mentioned.

Comment: It seems that the toString() methods doesn't return the content of the element. Why is that a problem?

Comment: That is not the problem, the next segment of my code uses this html element object for parsing, in which it expects the input should be the output of asXml method but in HtmlElement type only.

Comment: What do you mean by "in HtmlElement type only?"

Comment: String idStr = ParseUtil.parse(htmlElementObject);
This is the method which will be called ultimately whose method signature is
public static String parse(HtmlElement element)

Comment: The HtmlElement contains the child elements (otherwise, asXml() would not include them); the problem you have is with the toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

`.toString()` prints only the current DomElement, not the children.

You need to get the children, either by using XPath, something like:

```
List<HtmlElement> items = page.getByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'listContainer')]");
for (HtmlElement item : items) {
    List<HtmlElement> children = item.getByXPath(".//div");
    for (HtmlElement child : children) {
        System.out.println(child);
    }
}
```

Or

```
for (HtmlElement child : item.getHtmlElementDescendants()) {
    System.out.println(child);
}
```